# print div content from user control without opening a new window

Tags: asp.net, javascript, css

I have a USER CONTROL with a `<div>` tag and a button. I want to print the content of the `<div>` when the button is clicked. Only the content of the `div` and nothing else no matter where the control is used. This without opening a new window. I cannot find a solution that works with every browser!

Thank you!

Comment: When you say print the content of the div, you mean you want to make like a printer-friendly page with only the contents of the div?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be able to generate a CSS file that excludes everything except the `<div>`, something in the lines of:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
```

And the putting something like this in print.css:

```
* { display: none; }
#specialdiv { display: block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the server-side click handler of the button, send out the content you want to display:

```
protected void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Write(...the content of your div; be nice and add at least some html headers...);
    Response.End();
}
```

`Clear` removes everything from the output buffer, `Write` outputs your stuff and `End` stops processing the rest of your page.

Answer (score 0):

As kb said, use css to define what is and what isn't printed on a page.
If you want a print button which prints just a div follow kb's instructions. If you still want file->print to behave as normal however, change the page's (media="print") css prior to calling window.print() and revert it afterwards in the button's onclick function.

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news but there isn't a comprehensive print api for javascript!