# How to print multiple files with js and asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vbscript

I had to run some server side code to open multiple files via javascript something to this effect:

Assume r is just a reader with some data:

```
If r IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    Do While r.Read()
        'added below to replace \\ with http://
        strURL = Replace(CType(r("AttachmentLink"), String), "\\myServer\MyFolder\MyPath", "http://MyFolder/MyPath", , , CompareMethod.Text)
        'added below to replace \ with /
        strURL = Replace(strURL, "\", "/")
        sb.AppendLine("window.open('" & strURL & "', '_blank', 'menubar=no');")
    Loop
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "popup", sb.ToString(), True)
End If
```

This works great for opening multiple attachments...
but now I need to not only open them up but print them...

So I tried just taking what I had above and modifying a little:

```
Do While r.Read()
    'added below to replace \\ with http://
    strURL = Replace(CType(r("AttachmentLink"), String), "\\myServer\MyFolder\MyPath", "http://MyFolder/MyPath", , , CompareMethod.Text)
    'added below to replace \ with /
    strURL = Replace(strURL, "\", "/")
    sb.AppendLine("var oWindow = window.open('" & strURL & "', '_blank', 'menubar=no');")
    sb.AppendLine("oWindow.print();")
    sb.AppendLine("oWindow.close();")
Loop
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "popup", sb.ToString(), True)
```

This of course does not work, no error but nothing comes up.  I was hoping to get each window open up and a print dialog from javascript to pop up...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Due to browser javascript security reasons you're not allowed to print a child window.

What you could do is add a load script into those pages you'd like to print that will initiate printing from that child window instead.

[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089434/printing-the-contents-of-a-div-tag-without-a-pop-up-window-in-javascript/5089551#5089551) that shows a bit different aproach in a sense that:

1. it creates an `iframe`
2. loads some content in it and also
3. adds `onload` event to print it...

Comment: Errr...is there any way around this because I've seen people post stuff like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187400/printing-multiple-pdf-files-using-javascript

Comment: I dont know how to handle this in my situation :(