# Troubleshooting: How can I print() window of a specified elementById? (Without production breaking)

Tags: javascript, html, window, document, next.js13

**The problem I am facing:**
This function works as expected when in local development. However, in a production environment the styles break upon the first render of the new window (printWindow).

I have done a lot of troubleshooting and there seem to be no solutions. The application is running on nextjs 13.0.1.

Overall, I want to print by the `id` because there are other html elements on the page I do no want in the print view.

```
function printElementsById(id: string) {
  const elementHead = document.head.innerHTML
  const elementToPrint = document.getElementById(id)

  if (elementToPrint) {
    let printWindow: Window = window.open("", "", "width=1280,height=720")!

    printWindow.document.write(
      `
        <html>
          <head>
            ${elementHead}
            <style>
              @media print {
                .no-print {
                  display: none !important;
                }
              }
            </style>
          </head>
          <body>
            <div class="no-print" style="display: flex; justify-content: center">
              <button style="margin: 1rem 2rem" onclick="{window.print()}">
                Print page
              </button>
            </div>
            ${elementToPrint.innerHTML}
          </body>
        </html>
      `
    )
  }
}
```

**What this function does:**
Opens a new window with the contents we want to print and has a "Print page" button which will open a option to print.

Alternatively I tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089434/printing-the-contents-of-a-div-tag-without-a-pop-up-window-in-javascript) and the behavior is still occurring when I run in a production environment.